# How can i use the hash_pbkdf2()

Tags: php, pbkdf2

I just installed php 5.5 and do not know if I forgot to configure something to make the hash_pbkdf2 function working, which I have to do so that I can be using it?

edit: for the people who can not understand my problem, and avoid negative votes without a reason:

my php is 5.5.10 and when i use the hash_pbkdf2() says does not exist.

Comment: Cool people give negative vote but do not respond a question that I am having doubt even if it is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to [configure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/hash.configuration.php), but maybe you forgot to install the module? You can read more about the [hash module requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/hash.requirements.php).

Comment: Says it requires no configuration, and or any module, but the function still does not work for me.

Comment: Maybe you installed PHP without hash support? I found a backup solution in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php#113488).